# Clarification about location of a class in eclipse packages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

If that question was asked before, please disregard it. I was investigating the `HippieProposalComputer` class found in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java` package to help me write my own plugin. So I looked at the list of dependencies and one of them is `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HippieProposalProcessor` so when I looked up `org/eclipse/ui/texteditor` I was not able to find the `HippieProposalProcessor` class. I perform a `grep -r HippieProposalProcessor plugins` and the class was in the package `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor`

So my question are the packages  `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` and `org.eclipse.ui` the same since eclipse never throw an error when Hippie is used at content-assistor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistakenly assume that package names and plugin names are tight together. They are not.

In your case, the `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HippieProposalProcessor` is located in the correct package, but in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor` *plugin*.

Most probably, this is a result of a refactoring and splitting the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin into multiple smaller plugins, which resulted in a package, which doesn't have its plugin name as prefix.

Comment: You can find the plugin that contains a class from within eclipse using `CTRL+CHIGT+T`.  Looking for a particular class in the Eclipse APIs? http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_a_particular_class_from_an_Eclipse_plug-in%3F

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't matter. If you look at the source, there is an import for `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HippieProposalProcessor` in `HippieProposalComputer` which makes the class visible in the code.